# how to change flink fat jar to thin jar

Tags: maven, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, flink-streaming

can I move the dependency jars to hdfs, so I can run a thin jar without dependency jars?
the Operation and Maintenance Engineers do not allow me to move jar to flink lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what problem you are trying to solve, but you might want to consider an application mode deployment if you are using yarn:

```sh
./bin/flink run-application -t yarn-application \
  -Dyarn.provided.lib.dirs="hdfs://myhdfs/remote-flink-dist-dir" \
    "hdfs://myhdfs/jars/MyApplication.jar"
```

In this example, `MyApplication.jar` isn't a thin jar, but the job submission is very lightweight as the needed Flink jars and the application jar are picked up from HDFS rather than being shipped to the cluster by the client. Moreover, the application’s `main()` method is executed on the JobManager.

Application mode was introduced in Flink 1.11, and is described in detail in this blog post: [Application Deployment in Flink: Current State and the new Application Mode](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/07/14/application-mode.html).